# How to embed a javascript/jquery file in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: expressionengine

I need to embed jquery files in ExpressionEngine.

I have created the template js under the main site template group.

I know that the css is embedding with the following tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet=template_group/template}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

for css its {stylesheet=template_group/template}

I want to know what is the tag for embedding js files

```
<script src=" [-->> ?? <<--] " type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make sure that your template containing your javascript is of the "JavaScript" type, and link it using the standard path syntax:

`<script src="{path="scripts/myscript"}" type="text/javascript"></script>`